# Trying to convert SimpleXMLObject to HTML using PHP

Tags: php, html, xml-parsing

That is the first time for me to use the SimpleXMLobject, so I have have an XMLstring, which looks something like so:

```
"<Body><SoapResponse><response><code>0</code><message>Success</message><id>123</id></response><details><a>123</a><b>ABC</c><d>1</d><e>XYZ</e><f>df</f><g>1</g><h>10</h></details><secondarydetails><box1><boxname>wer</boxname><date>2013-11-29</date><expirydate>2013-12-29</expirydate><flag>S</flag></box1><box2><boxname>pos</boxname><date>2013-11-29</date><expirydate>2013-12-29</expirydate><flag>E</flag></SoapResponse></Body>"
```

I am trying to parse and convert it to html format, preferably html tables, but I found only the following code:

```
<pre><code>$xml = simplexml_load_string($soapresponse);
           function writeList($items){
           if($items === null)
           return;
           echo '&lt;ul&gt;';
           foreach($items as $item =&gt $children){
           echo '&lt;li&gt;'.$item;
           writeList($children);
           echo '&lt;/li&gt;';
           }
           echo '&lt;/ul&gt;';
           writeList($xml);</code></pre>
```

But the html displayed was just tags with no values something like this:

- SoapResponse

  - response

    code
- message

Can some one please help how to fix this? and it will be great if I can have it in table format, thank you so much for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($soapresponse);
```

You are then returned a simpleXMLElement. AS seen in the PHP documentation here:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php

This might get you a little closer:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($soapresponse);

// You need to build the table wrapper first
echo '<table>';

// The recursive function
function writeList($items){
    if($items === null)
        return;
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($items->children() as $i => $child){
        echo '<td>', $child->getName(), '</td><td>', (string)$child, '</td>';
        writeList($child);
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
writeList($xml);

echo '</table>';
```

It will product a table like so:

```
response    
code    0
message Success
id  123
details 
a   123
b   ABC
d   1
e   XYZ
f   df
g   1
h   10
secondarydetails    
box1    
boxname         wer
date            2013-11-29
expirydate  2013-12-29
flag            S
box2    
boxname     pos
date            2013-11-29
expirydate  2013-12-29
flag            E
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works but I have one more question if you do not mind, if I want to make the header of the array (i.e response, secondarydetailsdetails, etc) for different font how can I do so, how can I change certain element format in the simplexmlobject, I was googling on how to access certain simplexmlobject by its number and change its format I did not find much help, can you help me in so please?

Answer (score 0):

In your XML string opening and closing tag are missed and for parsing xml to HTML you can use SimpleXMLElement. it will convert xml to html like below code.

```
   <?php
    $news=new SimpleXMLElement('
    <Body><SoapResponse><response><code>0</code><message>Success</message><id>123</id></response><details><a href="#">123</a><b>ABC</b><d>1</d><e>XYZ</e><f>df</f><g>1</g><h>10</h></details><secondarydetails><box1><boxname>wer</boxname><date>2013-11-29</date><expirydate>2013-12-29</expirydate><flag>S</flag></box1><box2><boxname>pos</boxname><date>2013-11-29</date><expirydate>2013-12-29</expirydate><flag>E</flag></box2></secondarydetails></SoapResponse></Body>');
    print_r($news);
    ?>
```

and for more information see [simplexmlelement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php)